# Unable to debug the error in HTTPPOST2()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can someone help me identify the syntax error that I am making in the HttpPost call below. Help is appreciated. This is the log that I could request from the marketing cloud support team

> ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException: An error occurred when
>   attempting to resolve a function call. See inner exception for detail.
>   Function Call:
>
> HTTPPost2('https://ri.dd.igee.net/v1/consumer/interaction','application/json','{"interaction_type":
>   "SMS", "interaction_source": "MARKETING_CLOUD", "interaction_subject":
>   "VALIDATION_REQUESTED", "interaction_brand_family": "aa", "member_id":
>   "833", "interaction": { "person_id": "833", "channel": "SMS",
>   "mobile_number": "14804544447"
>   }}',false,'status','response','["Authorization", "API-Version",
>   "API-Key"]','["Bearer wwweewewew227eu4wNpgX", "v3",
>   "QkU0QjR324523452354gefgsdfvdftRDFFRUVCQTNCQ0Ez"]')
>
> Index: 593 Content Type: Text Substitution Level: Subscriber Message Context: SMS Error Code: OMM_SCRIPT_SYNTAX_ERR - from
>   OMMCommon --> 
>       --- inner exception 2--- 
>       ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionException: Invalid characters appear at the end of the parameter value

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other quotes inside the json than you use for the string or you need to escape them.

> HTTPPost2('https://ri.dd.igee.net/v1/consumer/interaction','application/json','{"interaction_type":
>   "SMS", "interaction_source": "MARKETING_CLOUD", "interaction_subject":
>   "VALIDATION_REQUESTED", "interaction_brand_family": "aa", "member_id":
>   "833", "interaction": {"person_id": "833", "channel": "SMS",
>   "mobile_number":
>   "14804544447"}}',false,'status','response','["Authorization",
>   "API-Version", "API-Key"]','["Bearer wwweewewew227eu4wNpgX", "v3",
>   "QkU0QjR324523452354gefgsdfvdftRDFFRUVCQTNCQ0Ez"]')

Comment: Thanks for you input Markus. I tried using the other quotes as you suggested and still have the same error.

Comment: I suppose the format of the header names and values could be wrong, but in the marketing cloud documentation I couldn't find anything on the format of these two parameters and I've never used them before. Maybe the headers are just a comma/semicolon/space separated list?

Answer (score 0):

Each additional header should be formatted in a comma separated fashion and your status and response are variable that you can then print or use... I made adjustments to you code below:

> HTTPPost2('https://ri.dd.igee.net/v1/consumer/interaction','application/json','{"interaction_type":
>   "SMS", "interaction_source": "MARKETING_CLOUD", "interaction_subject":
>   "VALIDATION_REQUESTED", "interaction_brand_family": "aa", "member_id":
>   "833", "interaction": { "person_id": "833", "channel": "SMS",
>   "mobile_number": "14804544447"
>   }}',false,@status,@response,'Authorization', 'Bearer
>   wwweewewew227eu4wNpgX', 'API-Version', 'v3', 'API-Key',
>   'QkU0QjR324523452354gefgsdfvdftRDFFRUVCQTNCQ0Ez')